# Dart Command Line app: Count number of lines in text

Tags: flutter, dart

Hello I am just starting to learn Dart and Flutter and I am facing a problem. I have a text (actually it is the default code from the main.dart file of a new Flutter project) and I need to count the number of lines in this text/code and output it via the Dart command line. I also need to define a class CodeLineCounter for it. The problem is that I don't understand at all how this can be done and can't find any information on this topic. Can anyone please explain or show how to do this?

I tried to use this definition, but it's wrong.

```
class CodeLineCounter {
  void display(){
var text = """
  // This is the theme of your application.
  //
  // Try running your application with "flutter run". You'll see the
  // application has a blue toolbar. Then, without quitting the app, try
  // changing the primarySwatch below to Colors.green and then invoke
  // "hot reload" (press "r" in the console where you ran "flutter run",
  // or simply save your changes to "hot reload" in a Flutter IDE).
  // Notice that the counter didn't reset back to zero; the application
  // is not restarted.
  """;
Map<String, int> number = Map();
var numberOfLines = text.readAsLinesSync().length;
number["Lines in main.dart"] = numberOfLines;

print(number);
  }
}

void main(){
 CodeLineCounter lines_counter=CodeLineCounter();
 lines_counter.display();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`readAsLinesSync`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.10.4/dart-io/File/readAsLinesSync.html) is for [`File`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.10.4/dart-io/File-class.html) objects which are references to files on the filesystem. In your example your [`String`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.10.4/dart-core/String-class.html) are already loaded (since it is inside the application) so you cannot call [`readAsLinesSync`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.10.4/dart-io/File/readAsLinesSync.html).

Instead you can use [`LineSplitter`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.10.4/dart-convert/LineSplitter-class.html) which are part of [`dart:convert`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.10.4/dart-convert/dart-convert-library.html):

```
var numberOfLines = LineSplitter().convert(text).length;
```

So you code would be:

```
import 'dart:convert';

class CodeLineCounter {
  void display(){
    var text = """
  // This is the theme of your application.
  //
  // Try running your application with "flutter run". You'll see the
  // application has a blue toolbar. Then, without quitting the app, try
  // changing the primarySwatch below to Colors.green and then invoke
  // "hot reload" (press "r" in the console where you ran "flutter run",
  // or simply save your changes to "hot reload" in a Flutter IDE).
  // Notice that the counter didn't reset back to zero; the application
  // is not restarted.
  """;
    Map<String, int> number = Map();
    var numberOfLines = LineSplitter().convert(text).length;
    number["Lines in main.dart"] = numberOfLines;

    print(number);
  }
}

void main(){
  CodeLineCounter lines_counter=CodeLineCounter();
  lines_counter.display();
}
```